# Как распарсить .txt файл с кириллицей?

Tags: php

Так получилсось, что логи какое-то время сохранились в .txt файл, но кирилица там в таком формате:

```
{"city":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430","agency":"TestAgency"...
```

Какой параметр писать, чтобы при чтении файла у меня вывелась нормально кириллица?

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что сейчас будет выводиться как-то не так?

Comment: сделайте print_r(json_decode('{"city":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430","agency":"TestAgency"}'));` все будет отлично

Answer (score 0):

У вас данные вывелись в формате JSON. Достаточно прочитать эту строку, декодировать ее в объект или массив JSON и можно будет прочитать кириллические строки.

Можно это сделать так как подсказали в комментарии

```
<?php

$str = '{"city":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"}';

$data = json_decode($str);

print_r($data);
```

Это код выведет

```
stdClass Object
(
    [city] => Москва
)
```

Но этот вариант сработает, если вы можете считать файл в PHP скрипте и внутри файла всегда будет валидный JSON.

Еще как вариант можно конвертировать все эти символы с помощью регулярного выражения

```
$str = '{"city":"\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430"}';
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\\\\u([0-9-a-f]{4})/", 
    function($matches) {return mb_chr(intval($matches[1], 16));}, 
    $str
);
echo($str);
```

Т.е. находим вхождение **\u** и четырех символов шестнадцетиричного кода. Код  приводим к целому числу по базису 16 и по этому коду получаем символ.